# Remote view controller crashes in IOS6 on iPhone4 when opening an SMS view

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, ios6

I get the following error message in the output window:

**Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!**

I have read that the SMS view in IOS6 runs in its own thread which might explain the problem.

Is there any available information about his issue?

Comment: I got the same error, but with YES as a parameter. Searched all over the place but still can't solve my issue. I am displaying the SMS compose VC and mail compose VC; the mail one works and the SMS never shows... And both of them work on iOS 5...

Comment: Try to use the NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to make the SMS view display, delayed in its own "thread" in the same fashion that you use setTimeout in JavaScript.

Comment: the message composer does **not** run in a thread of the application, but as a XPC service i.e. another process

Comment: Hmm, I've seen this (with the "NO" !)  Unfortunately the code base involved (not me) has a big tangle of threaded code. It's suspicious, now that I know the SMS runs on another XPC Service.  (Thanks for that info, Phix).  Rebooting the device does not help.

Comment: Note - one simple problem.  Often you come to sending an SMS< after using the PersonPicker.  Be SURE to dismiss the PersonPicker modal, before bringing up the SMS one.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same issue (Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!). But when i presented the message composer with 1.0 delay, it showed the message composer. Hope somebody will find this as useful & save their valuable time.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showLaterThisSMS:) 
           withObject:messageComposeViewController
           afterDelay:1.0f];


-(void)showLaterThisSMS:(MFMessageComposeViewController*)messageComposeViewController{

    [self presentViewController:messageComposeViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Helping another user related to a [UIActivityViewController reports "Remote compose controller timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676500/ios-6-uiactivityviewcontroller-timeout-bug/13692785#13692785), we concluded that the problem was a specific device and when he rebooted the device, the problem disappeared.