# UIActivityViewController reports "Remote compose controller timed out"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I get this in the Xcode console when tapping on my App's share via Message: The Mail one works perfectly fine however. The Message controller never displays obviously, which makes this annoying in a shipped app.

```
Remote compose controller timed out (YES)!
```

Is this an Apple bug? It only started to happen today.

Code:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
    NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:textToShare, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                  applicationActivities:nil];

    activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
    {
        NSLog(@" activityType: %@", activityType);
        NSLog(@" completed: %i", completed);
    };

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];

        CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        [self.popover
                    presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated question above with the code I'm using.

Comment: I'm still having the bug after your recommendations. See my updated code in my question above.

Comment: I am customizing my table view, but i'm not using the 'appearance' UI. I'm stumped!

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you're not alone. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259047/remote-view-controller-crashes-in-ios6-on-iphone4-when-opening-an-sms-view or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575192/presenting-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-broken-in-ios-6

Comment: Thanks Rob, rebooting my iPhone 5 solved the problem! Hope iOS 6.1 squashes these bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code. It works without problem on my devices. You might want to try rebooting your device or trying on another device.

The few isolated references that I found to this problem were related to beta versions of iOS 6 or other people suffering from the occasional crash, so perhaps we're just slowing working through the kinks in this messaging UI.